# Executing jQuery code during form submission

Tags: forms

I developed a module to show an "End" button on the node edit form, and it works fine.

```
function renew_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['property_endlease'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('End'),
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 15,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

I want that, when users click on that button, some fields are changed from jQuery code.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't show any alert, even though the form is submitted.

```
jQuery('#edit-property-end').click(function (event) {
  alert('');
});
```

I want to submit the form after the jQuery code is executed.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   $form['actions']['property_endlease'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('End'),
            '#access' => TRUE,
            '#weight' => 15,
            '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "javascript:test();"),

        );
```

and create a custom js

```
function test()  {
//your code 
}
```

Hope it will work